# How to resolve "PropertiesUtil cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, xml, apache, rest, http

I have installed both **JAVA8** and **JAVA7**, Also I am using **eclipse Mars 2.**

I have installed **eclipse Mars 2** with **JAVA7**.

Comment: Q1: Did the code compile before?  Or is this a project that you have imported from somewhere?  Q2: Is it a Maven-based project?

Answer (score 0):

It is usual with Eclipse to have the build messed up. Make sure Build automatically is checked and Clean. If it doesn't work, restart Eclipse and do again.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Yes I have done both clear and restart. Do I need to add any jar related to PropertiesUtil ??

Comment: If the project is Maven, 
right click the "Maven Dependencies"-->"Build Path"-->"Remove from the build path";   right click the project ,navigate to "Maven"--->"Update project....";
Then the import issue should be solved.